# Make wordpress pages accessible for Woocommerce logged in users only

Tags: pages, woocommerce-offtopic, login

I have created one page on my WordPress that I want to set only woocommerce user can view it. That mean they must logged in first to be able to view it. For unregistered user if they try to access to that page, we will redirect them to my-account page.

I found this similar solution but this only work for woocommerce pages but how to insert to code for wordpress pages. This is the code:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(site_url('my-account/'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Let say my page is `mydomainname.com/wordpress-pages`

How to be able to restrict that pages? looking forward your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your page slug in if condition too.

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_page('wordpress-pages'))
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(site_url('my-account/'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Comment: Sumit, your solution work perfectly. Thanks you very much for your kind help.